# Combination Generator with random result

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a generator that combines names into pairs then picks a random pair when a button is pressed.

How do I make the result only 1 random pair? and how do I add it to a button?

```js
const result = [];
result.length = 2;

function combine(input, len, start) {
  if (len === 0) {
    console.log(result.join(" x "));
    return;
  }
  for (var i = start; i <= input.length - len; i++) {
    result[result.length - len] = input[i];
    combine(input, len - 1, i + 1);
  }
}

const Names = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5'];

combine(Names, result.length, 0);
```

```html
<div class="Generator">
  <div id="button"></div>
  <button id="button1">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all the pairs in an array, then select a random array element.

Comment: ... that plus addEventListener on the button element to call a function that selects the random pair

Comment: Why do you use recursion in a loop if you want a single random pair?

Comment: You already have `Names` do the picking in your button click event, no need to pre-generate anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation would be:

1. choose 1st random element from the array
2. choose 2nd random element from the array (remove the 1st selected random element)
3. the combination of element1 and element2 will produce the random pair

```js
const names = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5'];

function randomPair(arr) {
  const index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const firstElem = arr[index1];
  
  // remove firstElement from array since equal pairs aren't allowed
  const newArr = arr.filter(x => x !== firstElem);
  const index2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * newArr.length);
  const secondElem = newArr[index2];

  return firstElem + 'x' + secondElem;
}


document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', 
function() {this.textContent=randomPair(names);});
```

```html
<div class="Generator">
  <button id="button1">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @prisonerorsavior check the code again, I added the output to the button name